# How to Modify an Instance in Another Class with AFNetworking - Creating API Client

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, afnetworking

Having this issue, because I'm trying to develop my code. Before, I was using AFNetworking methods in the classes, but I got 4 of them. Instead of that repeatin sequence, I wanted to have APIClient, which has the methods. I implemented some methods but my issue is about just two of them.

So, in APIClient.m I have the followings:

```
+(void)GetCurrencyInformationFrom:(NSString *)URLString to:(NSArray *) array inThe:(UITableView *) tableView{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; // User informations.
    NSString *accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"accessToken"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:accessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Token"];

    NSLog(@"access token: %@", accessToken);
    NSLog(@"id: %@", [defaults objectForKey:@"ID"]);

    [manager GET:URLString parameters:nil  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [self update:array withDictionary:responseObject inThe:tableView];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error 2: %@", error);
    }];
}

+(void)update:(NSArray *)array withDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary inThe:(UITableView *) tableView{
    NSLog(@"Data Count: %lu", [dictionary[@"Data"] count]);
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:dictionary[@"Data"]];
    NSLog(@"Array Count: %lu", [array count]);
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Those methods are called in Table View classes. For example, one of my classes I called within the `viewload` those:

```
NSString *URL = @"http://api-dvzalt.azurewebsites.net/api/Currency/Doviz";

[APIClient GetCurrencyInformationFrom:URL to:currencyArray inThe: tableView];
```

For debugging, I am printing the Data count and Array count (Both you can find in update:withDictionary:inThe: method) and number of rows (in the table class). It's normal to number of rows to be zero at the beginning since it is asychronous, however, after I reload my tableView, i.e. after everything is done (see [tableView reloatData] in update:withDictionary:inThe method) number of rows remains zero, where Data and Array's count are 20. And of course, with zero rows, nothing showed up on the table. So, basically my problem is the currencyArray I'm giving to method doesn't change after it comes back to the tableView again even it is changing in the APIClient class.

I feel like it is a simple mistake, but I can't see where it is. Glad if you can help me to find it.

Thanks!

Comment: You really should stick to cocoa coding conventions

Comment: What I am not using properly ?

Comment: Probably you are not using apple's documentation correctly.

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Well whoever he's downvoting is easy, explaining is the hard part.That question is well asked. You might be telling me whats wrong with it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't really like answering my question. However in this case, I bet there are too many newbie people around and searching for the same problem I have. I couldn't find any solution for 4 days. Have been searching on net and asking here, but nowhere I found the solution I needed. Maybe it will be not the case for you, but certainly it will at least take 1 day long, if it is the first time. So, I will give a try to make beginners like me understand deeply.

At first, creating and having a class like APIClient is generally a good idea. It is just a class that you can easily use when you are going to take data from internet. However, things are getting complicated for beginners since we are mostly got used to synchronous execution.

If you are up trying modify your any instance in any class, what you have to do is, simply, not to give that instance to APIClient (or the class that has blocks) like me, instead trying to take any needed information from the APIClient. Like, if we can achieve the information coming from the APIClient, it is easy to that instance in the instance's own class. E.g. giving currencyArray to APIClient, and trying to update the array in APIClient is hard. On the other hand, it is easy to just taking the responceObject from APIClient, which will be exactly the JSON data coming from the URL you have.

Long story short, in that manner, I changed my code in the APIClient.m into this:

```
+(void)GetCurrencyInformationFrom:(NSString *)URLString to:(NSArray *) array inThe:(UITableView *) tableView{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; // User informations.
    NSString *accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"accessToken"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:accessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Token"];

    NSLog(@"access token: %@", accessToken);
    NSLog(@"id: %@", [defaults objectForKey:@"ID"]);

    [manager GET:URLString parameters:nil      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if(success) success(operation, responseObject)
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if(failure) failure(operation, error)
    }];
}
```

Note that I have no longer update:withDictionary:inThe: method, since the plan is taking the information to the instance's class, and update it there. not here.

For updating purpose, let's call in the `viewLoad` of the instance's class. So, the method will look like this:

```
[APIClient GetCurrencyInformationFrom:URL
                              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                   [self updateCurrencyArrayWithDictionary:responseObject];
                            } 
                              failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                   NSLog(@"Error 2: %@", error);
    }];
```

Again for updating purpose, I also added update method here instead of APIClient, which is not really necessary actually; instead we would have block type instance.

```
-(void)updateCurrencyArrayWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary{
    currencyArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:dictionary[@"Data"]];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Please note that the line `dictionary[@"Data"]];` would probably change according to your data.

So, that's it. This is just a simple example of how to create API client for the networking purpose of our application.

Hope, I can help someone in the future with this post.

Comment: The reason your original solution wasn't working is because to modify the value of the NSArray in the APIClient class you would need to pass it by reference. Setting the "array" variable in your method only changed it's value in that method, this is why the array property on the table view controller wasn't being updated.  Blocks and single responsibility are definitely the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that your `UITableView` has the correct data source set?

What do your `-numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` methods look like?

Comment: numberOfSectionsInTableView I made one, because I need one. And tableView:numberOfRowsInSection depends on the currencyArray, which I'm planning to change with calling APIClient's get method

Comment: And `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is returning 20?

Comment: There is the problem I have, it doesn't.

Comment: array became 20 in the update method but unfortunatelly, it doesn't stay 20 when it gets into the table. I can't carry it to the tableView.